# Extra Marshal Badges

Tags: bug, badges

Not that I'm one to complain about extra badges, but something seems to be up with the Marshal badge calculation, as I've just been awarded it two extra times on the main site. I've got 583 helpful flags, so not enough to earn it three times.

[image: marshall 1]

[image: marshall 2]

the [badge recipient list](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/71/marshal) has 35 entries, with a bunch of dupes.

Comment: On the plus side, this morning I woke up to find that I'd finally received the third of three separate gold badges for my 'Why is the Matrix green' question; 1 x Great Question, 1 x Great Answer and 1 x Famous Question. That has to be a site record, surely.

Comment: @Valorum I'm sure if you ask someone can find a SEDE query for you

Comment: @Valorum [Keen did it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/115402/which-finger-was-bb-8-sticking-up) before he upped and left.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - fair enough. Ooh. I've just spotted that I'm only a couple of votes away from a gold for my answer to that one.